# How do I get only digits after specific string by regex?

Tags: regex, dialogflow-es

I want to write a regex pattern that extract only 5 digits after 3 letters in Dialogflow. For example:

> Input string: `hrv 12345`. I want to extract only five digits 12345.

I wrote this pattern: `\w{3}\s*\d{5}` and Dialogflow capture `hrv 12345`. I have to write `\w{3}` to ensure Dialogflow only capture 5 digits right after 3 letters.

In Google Sheet, I write `(?:\w{3})` which mean just match, not capture and it work. But this pattern do not work in Dialogflow.

So, what is regex pattern help me extract only 5 digits right after 3 letters in Dialogflow?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Doesn't `\w{3}\s*(\d{5})` work?

Comment: It capture all string ```hrv 12345```, while I only need ```12345```.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before, but this might help.
After Dialogflow capture a value from pattern `\w{3}\s*\d{5}`, detected intent will have the value in intent parameter ([link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters#valfield)).

In webhook function, you can get the last 5 digits with substring like below ([link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_request)).

```js
// JavaScript
let val = queryResult.parameters.param-name;
let digits = val.substring(val.length-6, val.length-1);
```